# How can I automatically generate an expression in Sympy using the coefficients of a 5th-order expression?

Tags: python, expression, sympy

How can I automatically write a 5th order expression using a for loop using sympy in Python?

For example, let the expression be: y = 2x^5 + 3x^4 + 17x^3 + x^2 - 8x +101
I have the coefficients in the 5th order expression as a list. You can think of it like [101,-8,1,17,3,2].

I want to create a 5th order expression using the elements of this list using sympy.

I would be very grateful if you could help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
coeff = [101,-8,1,17,3,2]
# create a list of exponents going from 0 to 5 (included)
expon = list(range(len(coeff)))
# create a list of polynomial terms using list-comprehension syntax
# and sum up the elements
expr = sum(c * x**e for c, e in zip(coeff, expon))
```

Edit to satisfy comment:

```py
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
coeff = [101,-8,1,17,3,2]
# create a list of exponents going from 0 to 5 (included)
expon = list(range(len(coeff)))
terms = []
for c, e in zip(coeff, expon):
    terms.append(c * x**e)
expr = sum(terms)
```

Comment: It works, appreciated. How can we expand for loop in a readable way :) like 

for i in blablabla:
    ............
    ............

Comment: I updated the answer. If it helps, mark it as the solution to your question.

Comment: @KağanPeneklioğlu  Once you get used to [Python's list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/), you'll note that it is both more readable and less prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

`Poly` can accept a list of coefficients and the generator directly. It expects them in order from high to low. If you want an Expr, not a Poly, you can append the `as_expr()` call:

```
>>> little_endian = [101,-8,1,17,3,2]
>>> Poly(reversed(little_endian), x).as_expr()
2*x**5 + 3*x**4 + 17*x**3 + x**2 - 8*x + 101
```